# How To Get Back Group Administration

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Someone removed all admin and moderator of my group. Now how can I get back this group? Note: The group has no admin or moderator now.

Comment: You have been removed from the admin role, how do you know that group has not admin or moderator now?